# Need efficient Beautifulsoup webscrape with nested divs & spans into pandas dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the results of a sports tournament into a pandas dataframe where each row is a different fighter's name.

Here is my code:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1221/categories/1532871")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

body = list(soup.children)[1]
alldivs = list(body.children)[3]
sections = list(alldivs.children)[5]
division = list(sections.children)[1]
div_name = division.get_text().replace('\n','')
bracket = list(sections.children)[3]

import pandas as pd
data = []
div_name = division.get_text().replace('\n','')

bracket = list(sections.children)[3]
for i in bracket:

    bracket_title = [bt.get_text() for bt in bracket.select(".bracket-title")]
    location = [l.get_text() for l in bracket.select(".bracket-match-header__where")]
    time = [t.get_text() for t in bracket.select(".bracket-match-header__when")]
    fighter_rank = [fr.get_text() for fr in bracket.select(".match-card__competitor-n")]
    competitor_desc = [cd.get_text() for cd in bracket.select(".match-card__competitor-description")]
    loser_name = [ln.get_text() for ln in bracket.select(".match-competitor--loser")]

    data.append((div_name,bracket_title,location,time,fighter_rank,competitor_desc,loser_name))

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Division','Bracket','Location','Time','Rank','Fighter','Loser']))
df
```

However, this results in each cell by row containing a list. I modified it to the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = []
div_name = division.get_text().replace('\n','')

bracket2 = soup.find_all('div', class_='tournament-category__brackets')

for i in bracket2:

    bracketNo = i.find_all('div', class_='bracket-title')

    section = i.find_all('div', class_='tournament-category__bracket tournament-category__bracket-15')

    for a in section:
        cats = a.find_all('div', class_='tournament-category__match')

        for j in cats:
            fight = j.find_all('div', class_='bracket-match-header') 
            for k in fight:
                where = k.find('div', class_='bracket-match-header__where').get_text().replace('\n',' ')
                when = k.find('div', class_='bracket-match-header__when').get_text().replace('\n',' ')

            match = j.find_all('div', class_='match-card match-card--yellow')

            for b in match:

                rank = b.find_all('span', class_='match-card__competitor-n') 
                fighter = b.find_all('div', class_='match-card__competitor-name') 
                gym = b.find_all('div', class_='match-card__club-name') 
                loser = b.find_all('span', class_='match-competitor--loser') 

                data.append((div_name,bracketNo,when,where,rank,fighter,gym,loser,))

df1 = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Division','Bracket','Time','Location','Rank','Fighter','Gym','Loser']))
df1
```

There is only 1 division, so this will be the same in every row. There are 5 bracket categories (1/4,2/4,3/4,4/4,finals). I want the corresponding time/location for each bracket. Each rank, fighter, and gym have two in each cell and I want this to be one per row. The sections in the dataframe are of different lengths, so that is causing some issues.

Ideally I want the dataframe to look like the following:

```
Division    Bracket Time    Location    Rank    Fighter Gym Loser
Master 1 Male BLACK Middle  Bracket 1/4 Wed 08/21 at 10:08 AM   FIGHT 1: Mat 5  16  Jeffery Bynum Hammon Caique Jiu-Jitsu   None
Master 1 Male BLACK Middle  Bracket 1/4 Wed 08/21 at 10:08 AM   FIGHT 1: Mat 5  53  Fábio Junior Batista da Evolve MMA  Fábio Junior Batista da Evolve MMA
Master 1 Male BLACK Middle  Bracket 2/4 Wed 08/21 at 10:07 AM   FIGHT 1: Mat 6  14  André Felipe Maciel Fre Carlson Gracie  None
Master 1 Male BLACK Middle  Bracket 2/4 Wed 08/21 at 10:07 AM   FIGHT 1: Mat 6  50  Jerardo Linares Cleber Jiu Jitsu    Jerardo Linares Cleber Jiu Jitsu
```

Any advice would be extremely helpful. I tried to create nested loops and follow the structure, but the HTML tree was rather complicated for me. The least amount of formatting in the df is ideal as I will later loop this over multiple pages. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Next step - looping this program over multiple pages:

```
pages = [ #sample, no brackets
    'http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1221/categories/1533466', #example of category__bracket-1
    'http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1221/categories/1533387', #example of category__bracket-3
    'http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1221/categories/1533372', #example of category__bracket-7
    'http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1221/categories/1533022', #example of category__bracket-15
    'http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1221/categories/1532847',
    'http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1221/categories/1532871',  #example of category__bracket-15 plus finals
    'http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1221/categories/1532889', #example of bracket with two losers in a match, so throws an error in fight 32 on fighter a name
    'http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1221/categories/1532856', #example of no winner on fight 11 so throws error on fight be name
]
```

first I define the multiple links. This is a subset of 411 different divisions.

```
results = pd.DataFrame()
for page in pages:
    response = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    division = soup.find('span', {'class':'category-title__label category-title__age-division'}).text.strip()
    label = soup.find('i', {'class':'fa fa-mars'}).parent.text.strip()
    belt = soup.find('i', {'class':'fa fa-belt'}).parent.text.strip()
    weight = soup.find('i', {'class':'fa fa-weight'}).parent.text.strip()

    # PARSE BRACKETS
    brackets = soup.find_all(['div', {'class':'tournament-category__bracket tournament-category__bracket-15'},
                              'div', {'class':'tournament-category__bracket tournament-category__bracket-1'},
                             'div', {'class':'tournament-category__bracket tournament-category__bracket-3'},
                             'div', {'class':'tournament-category__bracket tournament-category__bracket-7'}])
    #results = pd.DataFrame()
    for bracket in brackets:
...etc
```

Is there a way to write into the programming how to account for different size divisions? The example at the top uses 4 brackets+finals and 15 match brackets. There are other divisions with 1 match, or 3, 7, or just 15 and not multiple brackets. Without segmenting out all links by size and re-writing the program, I'm wondering if there is an if/then statement I can add or try/except?

Comment: Consider using something like a [markdown table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) so you can share the desired output and have the spacing retained. Also, do you only want the brackets info (not the finals) and what happens in the _bye_ lines?

Comment: @QHarr I have not tried use a markdown table generator. I will check this out for future learning. Yes, I did try to deal with the Byes, but had issues. The answer below was able to add that in. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was tricky as some of the attributes included the loser of the match, and then for some reason, others didn't. So had to figure out a way to fill in those missing nulls.

But none-the-less I think I managed to fill it all in correctly. Just iterated through each match of each bracket, then append them all into one table. To fill in the missing `'Loser'` column, I sorted by Fight number, and basically looked at the rows with missing "Loser", and checked to see which fighter fought in a later match. Obviously, if the fighter had another match later, then his opponent was the loser.

**Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import natsort as ns


pages = [ #sample, no brackets
    'http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1221/categories/1533466', #example of category__bracket-1
    'http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1221/categories/1533387', #example of category__bracket-3
    'http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1221/categories/1533372', #example of category__bracket-7
    'http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1221/categories/1533022', #example of category__bracket-15
    'http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1221/categories/1532847',
    'http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1221/categories/1532871',  #example of category__bracket-15 plus finals
    'http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1221/categories/1532889', #example of bracket with two losers in a match, so throws an error in fight 32 on fighter a name
    'http://www.bjjcompsystem.com/tournaments/1221/categories/1532856', #example of no winner on fight 11 so throws error on fight be name
]

for url in pages:
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

        division = soup.find('span', {'class':'category-title__label category-title__age-division'}).text.strip()
        label = soup.find('i', {'class':'fa fa-mars'}).parent.text.strip()
        belt = soup.find('i', {'class':'fa fa-belt'}).parent.text.strip()
        weight = soup.find('i', {'class':'fa fa-weight'}).parent.text.strip()


        # PARSE BRACKETS
        #brackets = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'tournament-category__bracket tournament-category__bracket-15'})
        brackets = soup.select('div[class*="tournament-category__bracket tournament-category__bracket-"]')

        results = pd.DataFrame()
        for bracket in brackets:
            try:
                bracketTitle = bracket.find_previous_sibling('div').text
            except:
                bracketTitle = 'Bracket 1/1'

            rows = bracket.find_all('div', {'class':'row'})
            for row in rows:
                matches = row.find_all('div', {'class':'tournament-category__match'})
                for match in matches:
                    #match = matches[0]#delete
                    bye = False
                    try:
                        match.find("div", {"class": "match-card__bye"}).text
                        where = match.find("div", {"class": "match-card__bye"}).text
                        when = match.find("div", {"class": "match-card__bye"}).text
                        loser = match.find("div", {"class": "match-card__bye"}).text
                        fighter_b_name = match.find("div", {"class": "match-card__bye"}).text
                        fighter_b_rank = match.find("div", {"class": "match-card__bye"}).text
                        fighter_b_club = match.find("div", {"class": "match-card__bye"}).text
                        bye = True

                    except:
                        where = match.find('div',{'class':'bracket-match-header__where'}).text
                        when = match.find('div',{'class':'bracket-match-header__when'}).text

                    fighter_a_desc = match.find_all('div',{'class':'match-card__competitor'})[0]
                    try:
                        fighter_a_name = fighter_a_desc.find('div', {'class':'match-card__competitor-name'}).text
                    except:
                        fighter_a_name = 'UNKNOWN'
                    try:
                        fighter_a_rank = fighter_a_desc.find('span', {'class':'match-card__competitor-n'}).text
                    except:
                        fighter_a_rank = 'N/A'
                    try:
                        fighter_a_club = fighter_a_desc.find('div', {'class':'match-card__club-name'}).text
                    except:
                        fighter_a_club = 'N/A'

                    cols = ['Bracket Title','Divison','Label','Belt','Weight','Where','When','Rank','Fighter','Opponent', 'Opponent Rank' ,'Gym','Loser']

                    if bye == False:
                        fighter_b_desc = match.find_all('div',{'class':'match-card__competitor'})[1]
                        try:
                            fighter_b_name = fighter_b_desc.find('div', {'class':'match-card__competitor-name'}).text
                        except:
                            fighter_b_name = 'UNKNOWN'
                        try:
                            fighter_b_rank = fighter_b_desc.find('span', {'class':'match-card__competitor-n'}).text
                        except:
                            fighter_b_rank = 'N/A'
                        try:
                            fighter_b_club = fighter_b_desc.find('div', {'class':'match-card__club-name'}).text
                        except:
                            fighter_b_club = 'N/A'

                        try:
                            loser = match.find('span', {'class':'match-card__competitor-description match-competitor--loser'}).find('div', {'class':'match-card__competitor-name'}).text
                        except:
                            loser = None
                            #print ('Loser could not be idenetified by html class')
                        temp_df_b = pd.DataFrame([[bracketTitle,division, label, belt, weight, where, when, fighter_b_rank, fighter_b_name, fighter_a_name, fighter_a_rank, fighter_b_club ,loser]], columns=cols)

                    temp_df = pd.DataFrame([[bracketTitle,division, label, belt, weight, where, when, fighter_a_rank, fighter_a_name, fighter_b_name, fighter_b_rank, fighter_a_club ,loser]], columns=cols)

                    temp_df = temp_df.append(temp_df_b, sort=True)
                    results = results.append(temp_df, sort=True).reset_index(drop=True)


        # IDENTIFY LOSERS THAT WHERE NOT FOUND BY HTML ATTRIBUTES
        results['Fight Number'] = results['Where'].str.split('FIGHT ', expand=True)[1].str.split(':', expand=True)[0].fillna(0)
        results['Fight Number'] = pd.Categorical(results['Fight Number'], ordered=True, categories= ns.natsorted(results['Fight Number'].unique()))
        results = results.sort_values('Fight Number')  
        results = results.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)     

        for idx, row in results.iterrows():
            if row['Loser'] == None:
                idx_save = idx
                check = idx + 1
                fighter_check_name = row['Fighter']
                if fighter_check_name in list(results.loc[check:, 'Fighter']):
                    results.at[idx_save,'Loser'] = row['Opponent']
                else:
                    results.at[idx_save,'Loser'] = row['Fighter']

        print ('Processed url: %s' %url)
    except:
        print ('Error accessing url: %s' %url)
```

**Output:** I'm just showing the first 25 rows. 116 in total

```
print (results.head(25).to_string())
     Belt Bracket Title   Divison                             Fighter                               Gym Label                              Loser                           Opponent Opponent Rank Rank  Weight                   When           Where Fight Number
0   BLACK   Bracket 2/4  Master 1                Marcelo França Mafra                          CheckMat  Male                                BYE                                BYE           BYE    4  Middle                    BYE             BYE            0
1   BLACK   Bracket 4/4  Master 1            Dealonzio Jerome Jackson                  Team Lloyd Irvin  Male                                BYE                                BYE           BYE    5  Middle                    BYE             BYE            0
2   BLACK   Bracket 2/4  Master 1                  Oliver Leys Geddes                 Gracie Elite Team  Male                                BYE                                BYE           BYE    6  Middle                    BYE             BYE            0
3   BLACK   Bracket 1/4  Master 1         Gabriel Procópio da Fonseca                Brazilian Top Team  Male                                BYE                                BYE           BYE    9  Middle                    BYE             BYE            0
4   BLACK   Bracket 2/4  Master 1      Igor Mocaiber Peralva de Mello       Cicero Costha Internacional  Male                                BYE                                BYE           BYE   10  Middle                    BYE             BYE            0
5   BLACK   Bracket 1/4  Master 1               Sandro Gabriel Vieira                    Cantagalo Team  Male                                BYE                                BYE           BYE    1  Middle                    BYE             BYE            0
6   BLACK   Bracket 4/4  Master 1  Paulo Cesar Schauffler de Oliveira                 Gracie Elite Team  Male                                BYE                                BYE           BYE    8  Middle                    BYE             BYE            0
7   BLACK   Bracket 3/4  Master 1                 Paulo César Ledesma                    Atos Jiu-Jitsu  Male                                BYE                                BYE           BYE    7  Middle                    BYE             BYE            0
8   BLACK   Bracket 3/4  Master 1       Vitor Henrique Silva Oliveira                           GF Team  Male                                BYE                                BYE           BYE    2  Middle                    BYE             BYE            0
9   BLACK   Bracket 4/4  Master 1                 Clark Rouson Gracie                 Gracie Allegiance  Male                                BYE                                BYE           BYE    3  Middle                    BYE             BYE            0
10  BLACK   Bracket 4/4  Master 1              Phillip V. Fitzpatrick                          CheckMat  Male                Jonathan M. Perrine                Jonathan M. Perrine            29   45  Middle  Wed 08/21 at 10:06 AM  FIGHT 1: Mat 8            1
11  BLACK   Bracket 2/4  Master 1          André Felipe Maciel Freire                   Carlson Gracie   Male                    Jerardo Linares                    Jerardo Linares            50   14  Middle  Wed 08/21 at 10:07 AM  FIGHT 1: Mat 6            1
12  BLACK   Bracket 2/4  Master 1                     Jerardo Linares                  Cleber Jiu Jitsu  Male                    Jerardo Linares         André Felipe Maciel Freire            14   50  Middle  Wed 08/21 at 10:07 AM  FIGHT 1: Mat 6            1
13  BLACK   Bracket 1/4  Master 1        Fábio Junior Batista da Mata                        Evolve MMA  Male       Fábio Junior Batista da Mata              Jeffery Bynum Hammond            16   53  Middle  Wed 08/21 at 10:08 AM  FIGHT 1: Mat 5            1
14  BLACK   Bracket 4/4  Master 1                 Jonathan M. Perrine                    Gracie Humaita  Male                Jonathan M. Perrine             Phillip V. Fitzpatrick            45   29  Middle  Wed 08/21 at 10:06 AM  FIGHT 1: Mat 8            1
15  BLACK   Bracket 1/4  Master 1               Jeffery Bynum Hammond                  Caique Jiu-Jitsu  Male       Fábio Junior Batista da Mata       Fábio Junior Batista da Mata            53   16  Middle  Wed 08/21 at 10:08 AM  FIGHT 1: Mat 5            1
16  BLACK   Bracket 3/4  Master 1                      David Benzaken                          Teampact  Male              Evan Franklin Barrett              Evan Franklin Barrett            54   15  Middle  Wed 08/21 at 10:07 AM  FIGHT 1: Mat 7            1
17  BLACK   Bracket 3/4  Master 1               Evan Franklin Barrett           Zenith BJJ - Las Vegas   Male              Evan Franklin Barrett                     David Benzaken            15   54  Middle  Wed 08/21 at 10:07 AM  FIGHT 1: Mat 7            1
18  BLACK   Bracket 2/4  Master 1                     Nathan S Santos           Zenith BJJ - Las Vegas   Male                    Nathan S Santos              Jose A. Llanas-Campos            30   46  Middle  Wed 08/21 at 10:16 AM  FIGHT 2: Mat 6            2
19  BLACK   Bracket 3/4  Master 1                       Javier Arroyo               Team Shawn Hammonds  Male                      Javier Arroyo        Kaisar Adilevich Saulebayev            43   27  Middle  Wed 08/21 at 10:18 AM  FIGHT 2: Mat 7            2
20  BLACK   Bracket 4/4  Master 1              Manuel Ray Gonzales II                      Ralph Gracie  Male                Steven J. Patterson                Steven J. Patterson            13   49  Middle  Wed 08/21 at 10:10 AM  FIGHT 2: Mat 8            2
21  BLACK   Bracket 2/4  Master 1               Jose A. Llanas-Campos                 Ribeiro Jiu-Jitsu  Male                    Nathan S Santos                    Nathan S Santos            46   30  Middle  Wed 08/21 at 10:16 AM  FIGHT 2: Mat 6            2
22  BLACK   Bracket 4/4  Master 1                 Steven J. Patterson                         Brasa CTA  Male                Steven J. Patterson             Manuel Ray Gonzales II            49   13  Middle  Wed 08/21 at 10:10 AM  FIGHT 2: Mat 8            2
23  BLACK   Bracket 3/4  Master 1         Kaisar Adilevich Saulebayev  Charles Gracie Jiu-Jitsu Academy  Male                      Javier Arroyo                      Javier Arroyo            27   43  Middle  Wed 08/21 at 10:18 AM  FIGHT 2: Mat 7            2
24  BLACK   Bracket 1/4  Master 1                  Matthew Romino Fox                  Team Lloyd Irvin  Male  Thiago Alves Cavalcante Rodrigues  Thiago Alves Cavalcante Rodrigues            33   48  Middle  Wed 08/21 at 10:15 AM  FIGHT 2: Mat 5            2
```

Comment: interesting approach +

Comment: @chitown88 wow this answer is amazing. i'm going to be studying this for a bit. I like that you were able to deal with the fighters that got a Bye as well. I tried that but had more issues. I also like how to dealt with the loser category. Makes sense also how you nested the fighter description and their elements. Thank you so much for the thorough answer! I am very appreciative.

Comment: @Marie10 glad it worked out. Ya look it over and let me know if you have any questions or need me to explain anything.

Comment: @chitown88 Hi thanks again for your help! I have a follow up question - I'm now trying to loop this program over 411 divisions. Some of the divisions are different sizes. Our original example used 4 brackets or 15 matches +finals. However, some divisions have only 1,3,7,or just 15 matches. I've added code back to the top on the different division links and how I loop your program over multiple pages. Is there a way we can specify different categories for the bracket variable? (i.e. category__bracket-1 or 3 or 7 or 15) And if the finals is present, run code, or pass/continue if not?

Comment: Yup we can do that. When I get a chance to sit down I’ll write up a response

Comment: What we could actually do is instead of specifying specific bracket numbers, use the `.select` and find the class with the substring `'tournament-category__bracket tournament-category__bracket-'` Then for those fighter names issing, just use try/except and you could fill it with `None` or `'N/A'`, or `'Unknown'`, or whatever you want. I was also not able to access a couple of those links, so you might want to doble check those.

Comment: @chitown88 Yes, using .select did the trick! Also, it looks like they took down some of the bracket categories already, I only have a limited window after a tournament. Last, I tried to figure out a way to solve the errors, so the try/except solution helps me understand how to do that for the future. I want to THANK YOU for all your help on this and going back to figure out a more complicated task. When I'm more skilled, I will give back to the community in the same way. You rock!